# True-False condition inline on HTML element (checkbox)

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<input type='checkbox'>
```

I want to make conditional using jQuery, for example, if `data[1].condition` is `true`, then set it checked, if not then not.

May be something like:

```
<input type='checkbox' + if data[1].condition is false, unchecked + "'>

<input type='checkbox' + if data[1].condition is true, checked + "'>
```

Is there a way to set it inline? Something like:

```
<input type='checkbox' + data[1].condition | checked + "'>
```

Comment: Are you using any JS library or JS at all?

Comment: What templating language are you using? You can't do this in HTML only.

Comment: I'm confused... are you trying to avoid JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a way to do this inline.

Using jQuery...

```
if(data[1].condition === false){
    $('input').removeAttr('checked');
} else {
    $('input').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: No!

You cannot do this using HTML and JS the way you are using it. However, if you use a templating library like [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) then it can be done inline as you want to.

```
<input type="checkbox" <%= data[1].condition ? 'checked' : '' %> />
```

The other option is to use JS/jQuery to set the property using a script as done by Brad above.